# How to fix bug on Instagram embed

Tags: html, css, instagram, tailwind-css

I'm hard-coding a website for my student organisation using basic html-css-js and tailwind, in the website I inserted some embeds from instagram, but for some reason it keeps bugging out like so

[image: bugged instagram embed]

Does anyone know how to fix this? it should look like this normally

[image]

```css
.ig-embed {
  @apply block max-w-full overflow-hidden mb-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="ig-embed">
  <iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/CauLOXop4hS/embed/?cr=1&amp;v=14&amp;wp=652&amp;rd=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5501&amp;rp=%2F#%7B%22ci%22%3A0%2C%22os%22%3A159.59999999403954%2C%22ls%22%3A141.90000000596046%2C%22le%22%3A142.80000001192093%7D"
    allowtransparency="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="612" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: white; max-width: 540px;  width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); box-shadow: none; display: block; margin: 0px 0px 12px; min-width: 256px; padding: 0px;"></iframe>
  <script
    async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

Added some snippets to hopefully help

Comment: I see it's working, where is the bugging?

Comment: @Dhaifallah there's an extra white box under the 'add a comment' section on the bottom of the first embed

Comment: I think it's because of `margin: 0px 0px 12px;` try to delete `12px` because it means `margin-bottom:12px;` if this didn't work then it means this is happening because of instagram default styling